# Drupal views preview working but in actual page not?

Tags: views

I'm trying to show an image with teaser and name of the node type.

It is working in views preview, but not in the actual page.

can anyone suggest?

Comment: Please give some more information, like how you did set up your view. There could be several reasons.

Comment: It would he helpful to know what "not working" in this context means. Is it not showing up at all? Is it a block view, page view? Attachment? Details please. :)

Comment: You try with enabling the "Disable SQL rewriting" check box in Advanced -> Upcoming Events: Query options.